# Imprimir datos JSON después de redireccionar a otra página con Jquery

Tags: javascript, html5, json, css3

estoy tratando de imprimir en un `div` varios datos `JSON` que tengo dentro del `jquery` (solo es por testear rápido ahora con data local, se que no es nada (semánticamente hablando) ético tenerlo allí).

La cuestión es, cuando hago que redireccione al usuario después de rellenar el formulario que deben llenar con los datos, al hacer clic en enviar, lo envíe a otra página (**users.html**), y allí en el `div` que he mencionado al inicio, me imprima los datos del `JSON`.

Acá los ejempos:

1. https://jsfiddle.net/isirdiego/czy6v4nb/1/

> // En este está el formulario con su index principal.

2. https://jsfiddle.net/isirdiego/9dkx8dwb/

> // En este solo está la estructura de lo que debería ser el
>   **users.html** donde debería imprimirse todo.

Entiendo por lógica, que si no le paso algún parámetro al: `window.location.replace` o hago algo parecido, todo el código que está bajo él, nunca se va a ejecutar de manera correcta.

Alguna forma de hacerlo de otra forma?

Desde ya, muchas gracias por su pronta ayuda! :)

Comment: Puedes usar `ajax` para en vez de recargar toda la pagina solo recargar el div, así no perderías los datos solo los guardarías en variables y pintarlos en el div que dices. solo es una posible solución.

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurren varias soluciones. Quizás la más sencilla es usar `$.param()` si estás usando jquery. Con esto podrías pasar parámetros a la URL, de forma que te quedaría algo así :

http://localhost:puerto/users.html?user=user01&password=1&...

Luego en `users.html` simplemente parsear los parámetros y mostrar la información:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2091331/3866134

Como recomendación, si esto lo estás haciendo para una aplicación real, te desaconsejo que guardes información del usuario en el cliente como estás haciendo. Lo correcto sería que montaras un servidor que actuara sobre una base de datos.

Comment: Si pudieras editar el primer link, considerando que te hayas confundido. Gracias! n-n para probar con más exactitud.

Comment: El primer link es un ejemplo de como quedaría formateada tu URL con los parámetros que le pasas en el momento de window.location.replace(). En tu caso el código para formar la URL que comentamos sería window.location.replace('users.html?' + $.params(json.items[i])). Obviamente si no estás corriendo tu página web en ningún servidor HTTP, la parte de http ://localhost:puerto/ omítela, es tan solo un ejemplo. En tu caso se vería algo similar a  C://Path/donde/tengas/el/html/el_documento_html.html